# which is better way of building html using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently creating html ul in this way. First I am making an html variable. Then I am appending li to this html variable. Now I do not know whether this is a better way or not. While searching about this I came across this $(document.createElement('div'));. Is there any other better way? Please I need reason why my current approach is not good or good and why the other approach which I should follow is better than this?

```
function newsfeed(userid, username, msg, date_time) {
    var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + userid + "/picture";
    //var limit = 80;
    if(typeof(msg) != "undefined" && msg != "") {
        html += "<div class='container'>";
        html += "<li class='profile_image'><img src='" + url + "' /></li>";
        html += "<li class='from_name'>" + short_msg(username, true) + "</li>";
        html += "<li class='message'>" + short_msg(msg, false) + "</li>";
        html += "<li class='time_ago'>" + relative_time(date_time) + "</li>";
        html += "<li class='no_float'></li>";
        html += "</div>";
    }

    return html;
}
```

Comment: You have not accepted any answers to any of your questions. Some of those answers have been acceptable. It is considered rude to do that, after people have paid attention to your problems and put in their own time, free of charge to help you. Please take care of that.

Comment: @davin thanks I will withdraw my comment then.... I was thinking it wouldnt since it would just be put in as text I didnt know the dom would catch that.. I was basing it on inference

Comment: @LaurenceBurke, everything that gets rendered is in the dom. So every word/string/piece of text is in a TextNode, and every element/tag is it's own node in this big tree-like thing called the dom. The dom is just a fancy word for describing the web page you're looking at (the internals are slightly more complicated, because it also includes the structure and methods to interact with it).

Comment: @davin thanks for bringing my attention towards that. I tried make some of my previous questions as answered but I could not find any button or something through which I could make it answered. Can tell how can I do this? Thanks

Comment: @doforumda there should be a check mark below the numbers to the left of each question you need to click that.

Comment: Thanks I got it. But when I click it says that vote up requires 15 reputation but I do not have 15 yet :-(

Comment: I am still waiting for the best answer. I am confused. Can someone provide me official link where it describes the best approach? Thanks

Comment: `$(document.createElement('div'))` is fairly pointless. You should use either `document.createElement('div')` or `$('<div>')`.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, creating DOM elements the way you do, is the best one, when using jQuery. There's some explanation here:

http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/03/43439-reasons-to-use-append-correctly

Answer (score 1):

Use [jQuery.tmpl()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl/). For example:

```
<script id="tpl1" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <div class="container">
        <li class="profile_image"><img src="${url}" /></li>
        <li class="from_name">${username}</li>
        <li class="message">${msg}</li>
        <li class="time_ago">${date_time}</li>
        <li class="no_float"></li>
     </div>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function newsfeed(userid, username, msg, date_time) {
        var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + userid + "/picture";
        //var limit = 80;
        if(typeof(msg) != "undefined" && msg != "") {
            var $html = $('#tpl1'),tmpl({
                url: url,
                username: short_msg(username, true),
                msg: short_msg(msg, false),
                date_time: relative_time(date_time),

            }); 
            return $html.html();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Besides the improved readability (you can use syntax highlight tools on the HTML snippet etc.) this will html-encode your variables and give some protection against [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attacks. (You should still encode the URL manually, though.)

Comment: +1. Templating engines are good. jQuery's isn't the only one though.

Comment: Yeah using template engine is good to use but the approach which I used is it better? Can you tell me its benefits in terms of speed?

Comment: @davin: and jQuery.tmpl is not the only jQuery templating engine either. But it is the best supported one, and more or less official, and since the question was about jQuery, it is the obvoius choice IMHO.

Comment: @doforumda: string operations are fast, the bottleneck is when you insert the string into the page and the browser has to rebuild the DOM tree, fire events, recompute the layout... Compared to that, both the template engine and the manual string concatenation is lightning fast, so there is no advantage to do things manually. OTOH there are serious disadvantages: code readability suffers, and defending against XSS attacks becomes more difficult.